# React Lifting State Up

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, updates

I was studying this part of React documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html.

I have a similar problem in a project of mine, but with a slight difference. We can use the same example as the documentation, with a little alteration to suit my problem: let's suppose that instead of `<TemperatureInput />` I have `<Sensor />` components. This sensor captures temperature AND pressure, in two different forms inputs. My first idea was to capture these pressure and temperature inputs and put then on State, then pass it to the Sensor's props changeHandler function, which would actually be a function defined and working on the parent component. This last part is what the React documentation suggests, although they dont pass State to the function, but simply a variable (the event.target.value).  So, as an example, we would have something like:

```
class Sensor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {temperature:'',
                   pressure: ''}
    this.handleTemperatureChange = this.handleTemperatureChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePressureChange = this.handlePressureChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleTemperatureChange(e) {
    this.setState(temperature:e.target.value);
    this.props.onChange(this.state);
  }

  handlePressureChange(e) {
    this.setState(pressure:e.target.value);
    this.props.onChange(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    const temperature = this.props.temperature;
    return (
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Enter temperature and pressure:</legend>
        <input value={this.state.temperature}
               onChange={this.handleTemperatureChange} />
        <input value={this.state.pressure}
               onChange={this.handlePressureChange} />
      </fieldset>
    );
  }
}
```

My only problem with my modified approach is that State updates asynchronously, so when I pass State to the onChange props function, I may actually be passing the previous state.

I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Answer (score 4):

Correct. React state updates are asynchronous, so if trying to access state right after enqueueing an update it will still be the state from the *current* render cycle, not what you are expecting to see on the *next* render cycle.

Use a component lifecycle method (like `componentDidUpdate` to handle "react"ing to state update and correctly issue a side-effect, like calling a passed callback.

```
class Sensor extends React.Component {
  ...

  handleTemperatureChange(e) {
    this.setState(temperature:e.target.value);
  }

  handlePressureChange(e) {
    this.setState(pressure:e.target.value);
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { pressure, temperature } = this.state;
    if (prevState.pressure !=== pressure || 
      prevState.temperature !== temperature
    ) {
      this.props.onChange(state);
    }
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

*An* alternative is to use the `this.setState` callback function (the second argument) to run a function *after* the state has updated, though I think this pattern should be avoided. (*IMO it can cause more issues than it solves if misused, just stick to the lifecycle functions for effects*)

```
class Sensor extends React.Component {
  ...

  handleTemperatureChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      temperature:e.target.value,
      () => this.props.onChange(this.state),
    );
  }

  handlePressureChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      pressure:e.target.value,
      () => this.props.onChange(this.state),
    );
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
```

It appears as though you have *some* pressure and temperature state higher up in your tree, so I'm curious if this is the case and if simply proxying them as props through to the inputs would make more sense, i.e. something like:

```
const Sensor = ({ pressure, onChange, temperature }) => {
  const handleTemperatureChange = (e) => {
    onChange({ temperature: e.target.value });
  }

  const handlePressureChange = (e) => {
    onChange({ pressure: e.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Enter temperature and pressure:</legend>
      <input value={temperature} onChange={handleTemperatureChange} />
      <input value={pressure} onChange={handlePressureChange} />
    </fieldset>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer, Drew. It really clarified a lot of stuff. First of all, I loved that last piece of code. It looks very clean. And yes I do have temperature and pressure higher up in the tree. But Im quite new to React and dont yet feel safe enough to try stuff different from what I've learned (those basic class components and usual functional components). The only question remaining is why you think that the callback approach should be avoided.

Comment: @DaviAlefe That is a good question. To me it feels like an escape hatch, that other regular means address in a more intuitive way, and it was never taken out. I've seen too many new react devs go the route of chaining state updates via this callback, which can make debugging the already asynchronous nature of state updates even more difficult, mostly because they misunderstand component lifecycle. There is no synonymous state update callback for functional components, these use an `useEffect` hook to "react" to state changes, synonymous to `componentDidUpdate`.

Answer (score 2):

`setState` receives a callback that will fire after state changes have been applied. You can see this in the documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

```
this.setState({ ... }, () => this.props.onChange(this.state));
```

Comment: I actually saw that, but didnt quite understand how to fit it in my case. Why do you put { ... } as the first parameter?

Comment: @DaviAlefe, that first parameter can be anything depending on your states. this is just an example given by @Brenden. you state name and its value will go in place of `...`

Comment: I tried and it worked. I understood it now. Thanks a lot.